# Minecraft Showing Different World Lists when Launched through Steam

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Recently, my computer has been acting quite strangely.

My Minecraft saves list, server list and options menu have become bugged, and now display two different lists when either executed through Steam or not [I have linked Minecraft to Steam as a non-Steam game].

The 6 worlds on the longer list are my standard worlds, and used to load correctly when through Steam-related Minecraft and not. However, after a long while, neither of the Minecraft shortcuts displayed any worlds. I created 2 worlds for me and my friend to play on, as the old ones were seemingly removed [I should note that I can't access my %appdata% file, for some reason]. After about 3 weeks, I went back into Minecraft through Steam. When I looked through the saves, the 6 worlds were back. After that, I launched it regularly and it showed the 2 newer saves.

This doesn't need to be solved, it's completely fine as it is, I'd just like an explanation if there is one.

I cannot think of any reason why this is happening. There are two screenshots if you'd like further detail.

[image: Booted through Steam]

[image: Booted through Explorer]

Answer (score 1):

**Maybe** the environment variables are changed by Steam, and maybe the way this is done itself has changed.

Assuming you're on Windows: The Minecraft.exe downloads all necessary files to the folder ".Minecraft" in the appdata folder whose location is defined by an environment variable: If you type "set" in the command prompt, you'll see all variables, e.g. "APPDATA", which probably points to "C:\Users\YOU\AppData\Roaming". Set can also be used to create/change a variable.

Press WindowsKey+r, type "%appdata%", and press Enter. This opens the folder this environment variable points to, and you should see a ".Minecraft" folder in there.

The variables can be changed for a session e.g. via a batch file - without affecting the system or any other programs - which is a commonly known way of getting Minecraft to use a different folder, useful for having several versions (different mods, different sets of worlds). There are certainly several (say, 2) ".Minecraft" folders on your system, else you'd not see a different set of worlds sometimes.

Comment: I have accidentally found the "extra" file directory: C:\Users\[user_name]\.minecraft, where the 2 worlds are.
Also, I cannot access my %appdata% at this time, searching in Run says it cannot be found.

Comment: You can not search in run, so you probably are using a different kind of dialog. Opening %appdata% in Cortana works, so you're probably using Windows 7 and pasted %appdata% in that Windows' start menu box, which is not the run dialog.

Comment: This is how Minecraft behaves on Linux.